# Determining Location of Server Logs in PHP

Tags: php, apache, logging

In short, `phpinfo()` prints this:

```
Environment
...
APACHE_LOG_DIR  /var/log/apache2
...
```

`$_ENV` is empty.

`getenv('APACHE_LOG_DIR')` returns `/var/log`.

What I want is the value that phpinfo() returns. How do I get the actual location of the Apache logs? More specificaly, I want a directory that I can create a new file via `error_log` in.

Comment: try [`apache_getenv('APACHE_LOG_DIR')`](http://php.net/apache_getenv)

Comment: Are you looking at `Environment` or `Apache Environment` section?

Comment: @Gordon apache_getenv('APACHE_LOG_DIR') returns an empty string.

Comment: @Jack It's definitely the Environment section.

Comment: Perhaps $_ENV is somehow disabled then?

Comment: @Jack you'll have to tell me. It's a fresh apache and php install on Ubuntu 12.04 as of yesterday. I haven't changed any settings and I don't see anything in php.ini that suggests that it is (or could be) turned off.

Comment: @Jack scratch that last statement. Changing `variables_order` from `GPCS` to `EGPCS` fixes it. This, however, isn't a good solution for what I am doing, unfortunately. I also still don't understand why phpinfo() is showing something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variables_order` determines which superglobal gets created, as mentioned in [the manual](http://au.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). The `E` must be present for `$_ENV` to get created.